# TLSを有効にしているにもかかわらず、InternetExplorerで特定のWebサイトアクセス時に「このページは表示できません」とメッセージが表示される

Tags: ssl, internet-explorer, https

InternetExploreで特定のWebサイトアクセス時に以下の画像のような「このページは表示できません」とメッセージが表示されてしまいます。
InternetExplorerの詳細設定で、TLS1.0/1.1/1.2にチェックがついていることは確認しています。

またIEの設定のリセットも実施しましたが、当該現象は解消しませんでした。

このような場合どのような対処を行う必要があるのでしょうか。

[image: google接続時に表示される画面]

Comment: 書いてある通りで「サポートされていないプロトコル、または安全と見なされないRC4などの暗号スイートがサイトで使われている」るのでは？

Comment: InternetExplorerでサポートしていないTLS 1.3とかが必要になっているのでは？ Chromeの開発者ツールのSecurityで見ると`The connection to this site is encrypted and authenticated using TLS 1.3, X25519, and AES_128_GCM.`になっているようです。